# Tensor product and product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

If $A$ is an unital associative $\mathbb C-$algebra, and it admits a decomposition
$$
A = U V \; ,
$$
where $U,V$ are subalgebras of $A$ and $U \cap V= \mathbb C \textbf 1$, then can we show that
$$
A \cong U \otimes V \; ?
$$

If we consider the map
$$
\begin{matrix}
\varphi: & U \otimes V & \longrightarrow &  UV \\
& u_1 \otimes v_1 + \cdots +u_d \otimes v_d & \mapsto & u_1 v_1 + \cdots +u_d v_d 
\end{matrix}
$$
by universal enveloping property, it is well-defined.
And it is obviously surjective, but whether it is injective?

Comment: What is not obvious at all is that this is well-defined. You should define the morphism in the other direction.

Comment: You are right, I defined the morphism in the other direction but still failed to show it is well-defined.

Comment: The new map is well defined by the universal property, so that's no longer your question. \\ Does $U V$ mean $\{u v : u \in U, v \in V\}$, or the algebra it generates? If the latter, try two-by-two matrices, with upper and lower triangular subalgebras.

Comment: $UV$ means the latter, but I think $LU-$decomposition does not give a counter example because the intersection is all diagonal matrices, not $\mathbb C I$.

Comment: You can adapt it by taking for the upper-triangular only those with scalar diagonals.

Comment: Yes! It gives a counter example.